# How to perform "map" in bash?

Tags: bash, map-function

I'd like to add a bunch of directories to a command-line program, where each directory is supplied to a command-line option:

```
% cmd -I dir1 -I dir2 -I dir3 -I dir4 -I dir5
```

Suppose I can express the directories as a wildcard, is there a way to interleave it with "-I" in a single command? For example, in Ruby I can do:

```
system ["cmd", *Dir["dir*"].collect {|d| ["-I", d]}.flatten(1) ];
```

or, more succinctly in Perl:

```
system "cmd", map {("-I", $_)} <dir*>;
```

Comment: yeah, I should specify that I want to avoid having to do a loop and multiple statement.

Comment: map _is_ a loop. It just pretends not to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With directory names not containing whitespace, you can use parameter substitution

```
dirs=(dir*)
cmd ${dirs[@]/#/-I }
```

`/#` means "substitute at the beginning".

If the space after `-I` is not needed, you can use brace expansion (works with dirnames containing whitespace):

```
cmd -I'dir'{1..5}
```

This works with long options that use the equal sign, too:

```
cmd --capital-i=dir{1..5}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know string substitution can be applied to array as well. Also I forgot about brace expansion. Perhaps this is as close as can be for bash.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
for i in dir{1..4}; do value=$value" -I $i"; done; cmd $value
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.